# How can I Measure the Amount of Data Transfer for My Website?

Tags: web-server, hosting, web-hosting, website

Hello im trying to find out the ammount of my data transfer in and out? im building a website like cnn.com or cnnsi.com that kind of site, but i dont know how to messuare how many kilobytes will charge everytime that a user enter to my site, i mean the cache memory its not gonna be recounted or what can i do if i im doing an estimation based on the size o cnnsi.com can anyone help me?

I used the firebug to messure the amount of kb per load, but everytime i access it chage, and well i just need some examples, like what its a good size? because my page its gonna be around 350kb with everything? 350kb its to many for a sit? how could i reduce it?  what its the average for a site? or the cache memory counts in it?  how often i need to renew the cache memory in my servers?

I have some clues about the data transfer out, but what about the in? im just gonna let writting some text (like tweeter) to my users, that its gonna charge me to many data transfer in?

Help im very confused about the numbers !!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you look at [Y-Slow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).  This focuses on this sort thing as far as what is being cached and what isn't.  I think you might also find this [google tech talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTHvs3V8DBA) by it's creator to be a good introduction. Just keep in mind that the problems mentioned might not be [your problems](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/yslow-yahoos-problems-are-not-your-problems.html).

One of your conreate questions is how many users will have your data cached -- this is known as a "primed cache".  We really can't tell you, you will have to get the data over time after the site goes live. If you want a deeper understanding of how what gets cached is determined [this is a great tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) that covers it.

Those links might give you a good introduction about some more specific questions you can return and ask...